# UIWindow class: What's the difference between addSubview and setRootViewController

Tags: ios

The [manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW14) (Listing 5-2) says that the split view controller can be added to the UIWindow like thus:

```
[window addSubview:splitVC.view];
```

However, in an example code I have seen the following to be working perfectly fine.

```
[window setRootViewController:splitVC];
```

What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both do the same thing in this case but there are differences between `addSubview` and `setRootViewController`. `addSubView` is a method of `UIView` whereas `UIWindow` inherits from `UIView` and therefore the method, while its `rootviewcontroller` property is from `UIWindow` class. But the differences in the methods are

- `addSubview` adds the view into the callers view hierarchy and the
  calling object retains ownership.
- `setRootViewController` sets the view as the windows only view or main 
  view, if you will. An additional point is that it removes all subviews,if any, while addSubView does not do that.